# CSS different backgrounds for different divs

Tags: css, background, background-color, opacity

Something's not working.

The code is here: bambakids.com/menu

Content:

```
index.html
jquery.easing.1.3.js
smoothscroll.js
```

CSS Folder:

```
css/style.css
```

Let me know if you want the images too, although they shouldn't matter.

Goal:
For there to be a different background color on the contact div then on the main one (headermenu)

Comment: Isn't the contact div already a different color (lightgreen)?

Comment: Yes, but It is not actually becoming lightgreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html file you have in line 57

```
background-color: !red;
```

The `!` is not a valid part of the color name and needs to be removed.This looks like a typo to me. Doing that yields a red background on the "Hello!" placeholder.

You should look into using a linter. Such a tool could easily have spotted that error for you.